# Why does the definition of two variable differentiability include the partial derivatives of x and y?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

During calculus I was introduced to the definition of multi variable differentiability, which is defined as:

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(a+h, b+k)-f(a,b)-h\cdot f_x(a,b)-k\cdot f_y(a,b)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$

Now I don't seem to understand why the partial derivatives of x and y are inside the above definition. Let's says I would like to prove that a 2 variable function is differentiable at point (a,b), then it seems logical to state that differentiability means (this actually follows from the single variable definition):

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(a+h, b+k)-f(a,b)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=L_{h,k}$

Replacing $h$ and $k$ respectfully with $h=r\cos(\theta)$ and $k=r\sin(\theta)$ we acquire:

$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{f(a+r\cos\theta, b+r\sin\theta)-f(a,b)}{r}=L_{r,\theta}$

So if function $f$ is differentiable then for each angle $ 0 \le\theta\le360$ in degrees a corresponding limit $L$ should exist and therefore $f$ is differentiable if all the limits holds for very small $r$ and all angles. In fact, with this definition we also test whether the partial derivatives of x and y exist. Hence I don't comprehend why the definition of two variable differentiability must include the partials x and y, it simply doesn't make sense. All it seems to be proving is that any linearization around point (a,b) can be expressed as a combination of linearizations of $f_x$ and $f_y$.

Thanks in advance.

Jelle

Comment: You don't seem to understand what the derivative of a function of several variables is.  It is indeed the linear transformation that best approximates the function in a neighborhood of a point.  In the case of a real-valued function of a single variable, it's $x\mapsto f'(a)x$ which we can abbreviate to $f'(a)$, but in other cases, there's no way to represent it with a single number.

Comment: But that seems as if the definition of a multivariable function is different than that from a single variable function, why doesn't simply the definition I proposed earlier apply to multivariable differentiability? Lastly, what do you exactly mean by x -> f'(a)x?

Comment: The definitions are exactly the same in the multivariable and single variable case.  The function at the end is $g(x)=f'(a)x$.